# Stop my form moving on error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Why does my form shift down and a little to the right when validate.js displays an error? I just can't figure it out and where I can adjust this. I am using bootstrap. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

The jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#message").hide();

  //Define your validation rules.
  $("#bill_cost").validate({
    expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
    message: "error"

  });
//Define the event that will occur when the entire form is validated (on form submission)
  $('#myform').validated(function(){
    var formdata = $('#myform').serialize();
 //Post form data
    $.post('../php_includes/insert.php', formdata, function(data){
      //Process post response
      $("#message").html(data);
      $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
      $("#message").fadeOut(500); 
    });

    //Reset Form
    $('#myform')[0].reset(); 
  });

});
```

This is the form

```
<form class="form-inline" action="" id="myform" method="post">

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="bill_cost"></label>  
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <input id="bill_cost" name="bill_cost" type="text" placeholder="Bill Cost" class="form-control input-lg" required>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit1"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" id="submitButtonId" name="submit1"  class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>


</form>
```

Comment: Is an element being appended to the page when it displays the validation error? This can mess up other elements styling.

Comment: Where can manipulate the element to it does mess with the form layout?